# Why is it showing result for only `search.php?f=${searchInputTxt}` and not the other paths of the mealdb API?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, web-development-server

```js
function getMealList() {

  let searchInputTxt = document.getElementById('search-input').value.trim();

  const apiPaths = [

    `filter.php?i=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `search.php?s=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `search.php?f=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `filter.php?c=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `filter.php?a=${searchInputTxt}`

  ];

  // Create an array of promises for each API request

  const requests = apiPaths.map(apiPath =>

    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/${apiPath}`)

      .then(response => response.json())

  );

  // Use Promise.all to wait for all requests to resolve

  Promise.all(requests)

    .then(responses => {

      let html = "";

      let mealsFound = false;

      responses.forEach(data => {

        if (data.meals) {

          mealsFound = true;

          data.meals.forEach(meal => {

            html += `

              <div class="meal-item" data-id="${meal.idMeal}">

                <div class="meal-img">

                  <img src="${meal.strMealThumb}" alt="food">

                </div>

                <div class="meal-name">

                  <h3>${meal.strMeal}</h3>

                  <a href="#" class="recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>

                </div>

              </div>

            `;

          });

        }

      });

      if (mealsFound) {

        mealList.classList.remove('notFound');

      } else {

        html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";

        mealList.classList.add('notFound');

      }

      mealList.innerHTML = html;

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `promise.all`, if one of the promises fails, all of the calls fail. If you use `allSettled` it will not stop working.

Looking at the network requests the line `search.php?f=${searchInputTxt}` is not returning a response. So maybe you need to review the documentation on what `f` parameter is doing. Looking at the documentation, `f` is first letter. So if you are setting to a whole string, I guess they do not like that. :)

```js
const mealList = document.querySelector("#out");

let searchInputTxt = 'chicken';

  const apiPaths = [

    `filter.php?i=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `search.php?s=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `search.php?f=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `filter.php?c=${searchInputTxt}`,

    `filter.php?a=${searchInputTxt}`

  ];

  // Create an array of promises for each API request

  const requests = apiPaths.map(apiPath =>

    fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/${apiPath}`)

      .then(response => response.json())

  );

  // Use Promise.all to wait for all requests to resolve

  Promise.allSettled(requests)

    .then(responses => {

      let html = "";

      let mealsFound = false;

      responses.forEach(data => {

        if (data.value?.meals) {

          mealsFound = true;

          data.value.meals.forEach(meal => {

            html += `

              <div class="meal-item" data-id="${meal.idMeal}">

                <div class="meal-img">

                  <img src="${meal.strMealThumb}" alt="food">

                </div>

                <div class="meal-name">

                  <h3>${meal.strMeal}</h3>

                  <a href="#" class="recipe-btn">Get Recipe</a>

                </div>

              </div>

            `;

          });

        }

      });

      if (mealsFound) {

        mealList.classList.remove('notFound');

      } else {

        html = "Sorry, we didn't find any meal!";

        mealList.classList.add('notFound');

      }

      mealList.innerHTML = html;

    });
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: The same problem is persisting even after adding promise.allSettled

Comment: Did you change the call that fails? `search.php?f=${searchInputTxt}` fails when you provide invalid input. And the allSettled is working fine above with the changes I made. It is not a drop in replacement. Look at `if (data.value?.meals) {` to see the difference.